# When to use functional interfaces vs. type aliases?

Tags: kotlin

Could you give examples for these bullet points from Kotlin [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/fun-interfaces.html#functional-interfaces-vs-type-aliases) to clarify when to use functional interfaces vs. type aliases:

> - If your API needs to accept a function (any function) with some specific parameter and return types – use a simple functional type or define a type alias to give a shorter name to the corresponding functional type.
> - If your API accepts a more complex entity than a function – for
>   example, it has non-trivial contracts and/or operations on it that
>   can't be expressed in a functional type's signature – declare a
>   separate functional interface for it.

Also, what does the **API** mean in the given context?

Comment: API: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/API

Answer (score 0):

Think of the inner workings of modules, libraries, and other units of work as a black box.

The public-facing (or publicly exposed) stuff would be called their API as it's what allows you to interact or interface with said system.

In most cases, we reason about an API using the names of the exposed members and their signatures.

Point n°1 would be something like, let's say a mapper function. You have a type `MyType` which encapsulates a value, and you expose a function `foldMyType<T, R> = (reducer: R -> T -> R) -> R -> MyType<T> -> R`. You could just use the regular function as you type, but you might also want to give it a name `Reducer<T, R> = R -> T -> R` which would then give you `foldMyType<T, R> = (reducer: Reducer<T, R>) -> R -> MyType<T> -> R`.

Point n°2 can be explained with something that requires more constraints than a function signature lets on. It could be about something like requiring a type to be a Monad, or in Java and Kotlin's case, be able to use both functions and objects with a single named method as callables. Something like JDK's Supplier.

Comment: Could you come up with examples for bullet points?

Comment: Edited my answer to add examples